# DIsable multiple dates in pickadate.js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pickadate

I am working with pickadate in Application. Here I store holidays dynamically in database. I am fetching that dates with gem 'gon'.

```
gon.holidays = @holidays.collect { |holiday| [holiday.date] }
```

in application.js

```
 alert(gon.holidays);
```

output is

[image: When I load my page alert gives this output]

To disable dates in pickadate. I followed

```
$( '.new_leave_datepicker' ).pickadate({
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: 25,
        disable: [
           new Date([2015,06,22]),
            new Date([2015,06,23])
        ],
        min: Date.now()
    });
```

when I entered these static values then pickadate is disable these dates but I want to disable those dates that is coming from `gon gem`. Please guide me how to use each function of jquery with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please try this may be this will help you out

```
var dates = $( '.new_leave_datepicker' ).pickadate();
    picker = dates.pickadate('picker');
    jQuery.each(gon.holidays, function( val ){
        var newDate = new Date(val);
            disableDate = picker.get("disable", [newDate]);
    });
```